# Capture photo using plug in media shows screen as colored retcangles

Tags: xamarin, image-capture

i am trying to capture the photo via camera   using Media plugin. i have written the code below. But the image captured shows colored rectangles as attached image. I have tried almost everything. but all the time it show the same thing as shown in the attached image.

The button click for the photo capture is

```
if (brepeat == false)
{
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported && !CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Photo Capture and pick not supported", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var varFilePhoto = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions()
            {
                                    Name = "Img" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".jpg"
            }); ;


            if (varFilePhoto == null)
                return;

            
            imgCapture.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => {
                return varFilePhoto.GetStream();
            });
        }

        brepeat = true;
```

MainActivity.cs is

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        int requestPermissions = 1;
        string cameraPermission = Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera;

        if (!(ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, cameraPermission) == (int)Permission.Granted))
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { cameraPermission, }, requestPermissions);
        }

        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

Android Manifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>




        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
               android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K3gl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the colored rectangles as you attached image, Your code is running normally.

You test your code in an Android emulator. Because the emulator do not have physical camera, Android emulator provide this colored rectangles to simulating what you get when you turn on the physical camera.

If you run your code in the physical android device, you can get the view that physical camera get.

> But is there any way to test it, where i can see what i am taking picture?

If you want to see the taking picture, please add `SaveToAlbum = true,` in your take picture code like following code.(Note: If you want to get my simulate view of the camera, First of all, please update Android emulator in Android SDKs and Tools and use Android 9.0 or above emulator)

```
  var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Name = "Img" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".jpg",
                //Sets the properties of the photo file 
                SaveToAlbum = true,
               
            });
```

Here is running GIF. I take a picture, then find it in the temp folder(click the File app, select `Image`, choose the `temp` folder ).

[image]

> eg. trying to scan something

If you want to scan something, such as QR code, barcode, please use Android device to make a test.

Comment: That makes sense. But is there any way to test it, where i can see what i am taking picture? eg. trying to scan something

Comment: @pearl based on your question, I updated my answer, please see it.If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: Thanks Leon Lu. i used android device and it worked